# jQuery sortable - get element being sorted past

Tags: jquery, sorting

I am trying to prevent sorting if a condition matches based on the element "behind" the current sorting element.

```
<div id="sortable" class="ui-sortable">
<div class="queue-job" composite_key="58da0ab7d41e9a1c90e10eae" />
<div class="queue-job" composite_key="58da1f25b53d4e06bc149d27" />
<div class="queue-job" composite_key="58da0ab7d41e9a1c90e10eae" />
<div class="queue-job" composite_key="58da1b96b53d4e06bc149d26" />
</div>
```

In this case, div.queue-job at position 0 and position 2 has the same composite_key (58da0ab7d41e9a1c90e10eae).

Expected behaviour: If the user tries to sort $("div.queue-job")[0] past $("div.queue-job")[2], the sorting should stop.

This is what I have tried thus far. But this is only getting the siblings based on the initial position:

```
sort: function (e, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item[0]).attr("composite_key") === $(ui.item[0]).next().attr("composite_key")) {
          $(this).sortable("cancel");
    }
}
```

Comment: Has same ID? IDs must be unique...

Comment: Understood. This is for illustration purposes only. I am using an attribute the stores a composite-key value.

Comment: add html code not html image

Comment: Removed the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use update event instead of sort:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
 update: function (e, ui) {
    if ($(ui.item[0]).attr("composite_key") === $(ui.item[0]).next().attr("composite_key")) {
                $(this).sortable("cancel");
      }
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rvr6w93z/)**